# Selenium with Python- How to access a HTTP request and assert the content in real time

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation

I'm a QA automation Jr and I'm using Selenium with Python for my tests.

What I need at the moment is to access the requests during the test and asserting it´s content.

For example, performing a login, and after logging in, asserting that the payload of the "login" request is correct.

Could anyone provide me with information on how can I do that please?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is mainly use for testing the UI elements in a Web application. In order to do this you may need to setup a proxy so you can assert HTTP requests being sent during testing

I found the following link that maybe you can check out, but this is using Java, you may need to find a similar library that can be used for Python:
https://www.eviltester.com/webdriver/faqs/how-to-capture-http-messages/

Also if you want to test the HTTP request using your framework maybe you can consider setting up BDD tests with different client drivers to test on different levels
Ex.
API - test by calling APIs in your business logic
WebAPI - call REST API (this is where you can assert the HTTP calls)
UI - test using selenium

Ideally your application should implement Hexagonal architecture using Ports and Adapters

I created a simple template for this you may check. This one is implemented using C#, so may need to port to Python:
https://github.com/lorvindc/specflow-bdd-framework